# Custom BufferReader which reads and returns the string till a pattern is met

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, bufferedreader

java `BufferReader` has a method `readLine` which reads till `'\n'` or `'\r'` is read and then returns the line string. Example:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
BufferReader br  =new BufferReader(isr); 
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  // Do something 
}
```

I want a custom buffer which reads exactly like `BufferReader` but instead of returning line when it matches `'\n'`, it should return the string till it reads a pattern `10=???\u0001`.

It is basically a fix message which always ends with `10=???\u0001`, where `?` is number and `\u0001` is a character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be interested in using a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with a custom delimiter (set using [`useDelimiter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29)).

You really shouldn't override a method named `readLine` to do anything other than read lines (as delimited by `\r\n`, `\n\r` or `\n` based on your operating system). It's counter intuitive and can be confusing to yourself or others later down the road.

Comment: didn't meant overriding readLine(), sorry for the confusion. Scanner is good enough. Thank you.